# Creating symmetric weight kernels for Dense layer tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a weight matrix in TensorFlow as shown below

```
[[a, b],
 [c, b], 
 [a, d]]
```

where a, b, c, d are Tf.Variable. The gradient flow should change only the variables a, b, c, d. If I initialize 3 variables separately like, and then create the weight matrix **w** as follows:

```
a = tf.Variable(1., name='a', trainable=True)
b = tf.Variable(1., name='b', trainable=True)
c = tf.Variable(1., name='c', trainable=True)
d = tf.Variable(1., name='d', trainable=True)
w = tf.Variable([[a, b], [c, b], [a, d]], name='w')
```

The gradient flow is not tied to the variable and tape.gradient tells **None** for **a, b, c, d,** whereas it shows gradient for w. You can check the gradients by

```
x = [[1., 2., 3.]]
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    y = x @ w
    loss = y
print(tape.gradient(loss, [w, a, b, c, d]))
```

Is there some way to initialize the weight matrix with such constraints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a list instead of `tf.Variable` for `w`, since the nested variables do not seem to be recognized:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(1., name='a', trainable=True)
b = tf.Variable(1., name='b', trainable=True)
c = tf.Variable(1., name='c', trainable=True)
d = tf.Variable(1., name='d', trainable=True)
w = [[a, b], [c, b], [a, d]]

x = tf.constant([[1., 2., 3.]])
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    y = x @ w
    loss = y
print(*tape.gradient(loss, w), sep='\n')
```

```
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>]
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=2.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>]
[<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=4.0>, <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=float32, numpy=3.0>]
```

Comment: It is nice to know that tensorflow tensors work with lists directly. Thank you @AloneTogether